4D Fourier transform for spectral decomposition
I can't make sense of this Fourier relation in 1+3 spacetime:
$$\int_{F.C.}d^4 p\  e^{-i px} \rho(p^2)=\frac{1}{x^4}\ \ \to\ \ \rho(p^2)\propto p^2\ \ \ \ (1)$$
(where $F.C.$ stands for "forward light cone", meaning $p^2>0,\ p^0>0$)
I found this on some lectures over Conformal Field Theory. It would say, and I can't figure out this either, that:
$$\rho(p^2)=p^2 \propto \int_{F.C.}d^4q\ \delta[(p-q)^2]\delta(q^2)\ \ \ \ (2)$$
I'm not that handy with generalised Fourier transforms, so any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Also... I'm getting the sense that those "$\propto$" must contain some dimensional parameter, because both (1) and (2) don't add up in terms of energy dimensions, do they?

I'm not sure if what you're saying is correct. We start with
$$
\frac{1}{x^2} = \int_{FC} d^4 p e^{ip \cdot x} \rho(p^2)
$$
Replace $x^\mu \to \frac{1}{\lambda} x^\mu$ with $\lambda > 0$. Then,
$$
\lambda^2 \frac{1}{x^2} = \int_{FC} d^4 p e^{\frac{1}{\lambda} i p \cdot x} \rho(p^2)
$$
We now change integration variable $p^\mu \to \lambda p^\mu$. The region of integration stays the same since $\lambda > 0$. Then,
$$
\frac{1}{x^2} = \lambda^2 \int_{FC} d^4 p e^{  i p \cdot x} \rho(\lambda^2 p^2) = \int_{FC} d^4 p e^{ip \cdot x} \rho(p^2)
$$
Thus, at least on the forward lightcone, we have
$$
\rho(\lambda^2 p^2) = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \rho(p^2) \implies \rho(p^2) |_{FC} = \frac{A}{p^2} . 
$$
This is what you should be getting.

You're right, there was an error in my question, it should have been $\frac{1}{x^4}$. I apologise. Thank you for your answer anyway, it was helpful.
I’ve corrected the text. If I’m not mistaken, by following your same procedure, now what you should get is $$\rho(\lambda^2 p^2)=\rho(p^2)$$which doesn’t deliver $\rho(p^2)\propto p^2$.
What now?

I’m starting to think there might be a typo in the lectures, and that equation 2 should actually read $$\rho(p^2)\propto\int d^4q\ \delta[(p-q)^2]\delta(q^2)$$ this would mean a $\rho(p^2)$ with energy dimension 0, which agrees both with $\rho(\lambda^2 p^2)=\rho(p^2)$ and also (once integrated) with the dimension of the correlator.
Might this be it?

If you have copied everything correctly from the text, there is definitely a typo. Your correction would definitely give the correct set of self-consistent relations.
